# Calculate multiple lags for each variable in a df and store the results into nested lists

Tags: r, loops, nested-lists

I have a df (`data`) that I want to pass as an argument to a function `fun.lag_cols` to calculate (for each column in df) several lags. The results must be stored in a nested list, but my function seems to be missing (at least) one step.

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10,0,1)
               , x2 = rnorm(10,2,3)
               , x3 = rnorm(10,6,1))

fun.lag_cols <- function(x, lag_from = 0, lag_to = 2) {
  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  cols_x <- ncol(x)
  lst_lag <- list()
  
  for (i in 1:cols_x) {
    for(j in lag_from:lag_to) {
      lst_lag[[i]] <- dplyr::lag(x[,i],j)
    }
    
  }
  return(lst_lag)
}

output <- fun.lag_cols(data)
```

In this particular example, I would like to see `output` as a list of 3 elements (x1, x2, x3), each element a new list of 3 (one per lag 0, 1, 2).

My code seems to store only lag2 (in general, the maximum lag) for each variable, clearly not the expected result.

I am open to different approaches, as long as they provide the final output (nested list).

Thanks

Comment: FYI I also tried ```lst_lag[[i]][j] <- dplyr::lag(x[,i],j)``` , but I got the following error : Error in `*tmp*[[i]] : subscript out of bounds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could change the assignment of the 'lst_lag[[i]]' by concatenating the element with the `lag` value inside the nested loop.  In the function, there are two changes  - 1) initialize an output list with predefined length (`vector('list', ncol(x))`), 2) inside the nested loop, where we append those `i`th list elements with new child list elements by concatenating the already existing `list` with the new `list` created by wrapping the `lag` inside a `list`, while recursively updating the same list element (`<-`)

```
fun.lag_cols <- function(x, lag_from = 0, lag_to = 2) {
  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  cols_x <- ncol(x)
  lst_lag <- vector('list', ncol(x))
  
  for (i in 1:cols_x) {
    for(j in lag_from:lag_to) {
      lst_lag[[i]] <- c(lst_lag[[i]], list(dplyr::lag(x[,i],j)))
    }
    
  }
  return(lst_lag)
}
```

-testing

```
fun.lag_cols(data)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
 [1] -1.40431393 -2.22551238  0.06090537  0.77941726  1.10733091  1.20657717  0.71614034 -0.17990135  0.22058894  0.33598415

[[1]][[2]]
 [1]          NA -1.40431393 -2.22551238  0.06090537  0.77941726  1.10733091  1.20657717  0.71614034 -0.17990135  0.22058894

[[1]][[3]]
 [1]          NA          NA -1.40431393 -2.22551238  0.06090537  0.77941726  1.10733091  1.20657717  0.71614034 -0.17990135


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
 [1]  1.1334651  1.2385579  1.8930347 -4.7379766  2.0169352  0.7210822 -1.0322536  4.5446643  1.4421923  1.1316508

[[2]][[2]]
 [1]         NA  1.1334651  1.2385579  1.8930347 -4.7379766  2.0169352  0.7210822 -1.0322536  4.5446643  1.4421923

[[2]][[3]]
 [1]         NA         NA  1.1334651  1.2385579  1.8930347 -4.7379766  2.0169352  0.7210822 -1.0322536  4.5446643


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
 [1] 4.324912 5.114774 4.517017 7.001338 5.218430 4.408571 7.233504 6.875883 5.848294 4.696724

[[3]][[2]]
 [1]       NA 4.324912 5.114774 4.517017 7.001338 5.218430 4.408571 7.233504 6.875883 5.848294

[[3]][[3]]
 [1]       NA       NA 4.324912 5.114774 4.517017 7.001338 5.218430 4.408571 7.233504 6.875883
```

---

There is already a function available to do this i.e. `shift` from `data.table` which take a vectorized `n`

```
library(data.table)
shift(data, n = 0:2)
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, thank you very much (again!!!) - would you be so kind to explain your change to my function, please? `c(lst_lag[[i]], list(dplyr::lag(x[,i],j)))`

Comment: @GNicoletti I updated with some description.  Hope it helps.  This can be done more easily with `shift` from `data.table`

Comment: thank you, I have seen the extra comment, very useful - I also saw the last bit about `shift`, the problem is that using that function I can't get the nested list.

Comment: @GNicoletti For that you can do `lapply(data, shift, n = 0:2)`

Answer (score 1):

Using `lapply` :

```
fun.lag_cols <- function(x, lag_from = 0, lag_to = 2) {
  val <- lag_from:lag_to
  lapply(x, function(v) 
    setNames(lapply(val, function(n) dplyr::lag(v, n)), paste0('lag_', val)))
}

fun.lag_cols(data)

#$x1
#$x1$lag_0
# [1] -1.5095832 -0.2638919  0.5986575  3.3043298  0.9471048 -1.2154015
# [7]  0.8921754 -1.6614204 -0.2036500  0.9570701

#$x1$lag_1
# [1]         NA -1.5095832 -0.2638919  0.5986575  3.3043298  0.9471048
# [7] -1.2154015  0.8921754 -1.6614204 -0.2036500

#$x1$lag_2
# [1]         NA         NA -1.5095832 -0.2638919  0.5986575  3.3043298
# [7]  0.9471048 -1.2154015  0.8921754 -1.6614204


#$x2
#$x2$lag_0
# [1] -4.8181366  4.1741754  4.6560021 -0.5167334  1.5284542  8.7717049
# [7] -0.2104695  2.4273092  1.4985899  2.7356401

#$x2$lag_1
# [1]         NA -4.8181366  4.1741754  4.6560021 -0.5167334  1.5284542
# [7]  8.7717049 -0.2104695  2.4273092  1.4985899

#$x2$lag_2
# [1]         NA         NA -4.8181366  4.1741754  4.6560021 -0.5167334
# [7]  1.5284542  8.7717049 -0.2104695  2.4273092

#$x3
#$x3$lag_0
# [1] 7.712619 5.237124 5.798063 5.695696 5.127347 3.789074 5.830557
# [8] 3.801073 5.794048 5.227110

#$x3$lag_1
# [1]       NA 7.712619 5.237124 5.798063 5.695696 5.127347 3.789074
# [8] 5.830557 3.801073 5.794048

#$x3$lag_2
# [1]       NA       NA 7.712619 5.237124 5.798063 5.695696 5.127347
# [8] 3.789074 5.830557 3.801073
```

Comment: Hi @Ronak Shah, thank you very much for your answer... is there any way to rename the nested list inside the function? eg. `$xv[[n]]` >>>> `$xv[[lag_n]]`

Comment: How about the updated answer @GNicoletti ?

Comment: Yes, that's perfect, thank you very much, Ronak!